# What is the difference between post and poste?

Tags: word-meaning

I've seen both *post* and *poste* used in various places. Normally the *-e* ending signifies an adverb, but *post* is already an adverb on its own (as I understand it).

Is it an error to use *poste*, or does it have some different meaning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Post* on its own is a preposition, not an adverb, meaning that it describes a relationship between two entities (usually nouns or phrases). *Poste* is an adverb that modifies a verb. Examples:

1. *La hundo iras post mi* -> "The dog is going after/behind me". *Post* describes the relationship between me and the dog
2. *La hundo iris post kiam mi iris* -> "The dog went after I went". *Post* describes the relationship between the time the dog went and the time I went.
3. *Mi ne volas iri nun. Mi iros poste.* -> "I don't want to go now. I will go later". *Poste* modifies *iri*.

Comment: Kutime oni diras "post *kiam* mi iris".

Comment: @kristan Thank you, I was thinking of "antaŭ". I have edited that example.

Answer (score 10):

*Post* is a preposition, meaning "after". It can function as an adverb together with other words, for example:
*Mi dormos post horo.*

*Poste* on the other hand, is an adverb on its own, meaning "later".
*Mi dormos poste.*